# Restore database backup issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I downloaded the backup file from Mochahost website Pabel. But when i restore it on my local computer using SQL Server 2008 it gives me error.

Error Description:

```
Specified cast is not valid. (SqlManagerUI)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlRestoreDatabaseGeneral.PopulateGridWithBackupSetsFromDevices()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlRestoreDatabaseGeneral.GetBackupSetsFromDevices()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlRestoreDatabaseGeneral.textDeviceSelected_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Text(String value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.set_Text(String value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.set_Text(String value)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.SqlRestoreDatabaseGeneral.buttonSelectDevice_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I am using MS SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your backup is a newer version of SQL Server than what you have installed.

SQL Server is backwards compatible, but not forwards compatible. You'll need an instance newer or equal version of SQL Server to the backup you are trying to restore.

Comment: I am trying to restore backup of sql server 2012 to 2008 database.

Comment: You cannot restore backup taken on higher version to lower version